# Rearranging Three Similar Tables Based on ID and Stacked Values

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

Hello I have three tables and there is a process I need to identify to be able to structure these in preparation for a merge. Once I figure this out I feel that it will help me for a long time.

**The first table,** I have a table which, for each `vehicleID` involved in a traffic crash, inventories the damages (fender, rear end, etc) sustained to said `vehicleID` in a traffic crash. I would like to make, for each `VEHICLEID`, three new `IMPACTCODE` variables which display the **up to three** `IMPACTTYPE` codes (format `char`) listed in the table below:

```
itemindex    damageid    impacttype    vehicleid
1            2433        1             VEH1
2            2434        11            VEH1
3            2435        13            VEH1
1            2521        10            VEH012
2            2522        8             VEH012
```

I would like help to structure this into the following, where there is one line for each `vehicleID`:

```
vehicleid    impacttype_1     impacttype_2    impacttype_3    
VEH1         1                11              13
VEH012       10               8               NA
```

**For the second table,** I have a list of `personID's` involved in a traffic crash, and several `contributing circumstance` codes - which depict whether that `personID` was reported to be texting, speeding, normal, or other *contributing circumstance* to said crash. The amount of `codes` that can be assigned can go up to an unlimited amount, but **I want to keep just the first four**. I would like to do something similar as the first, but in case of this table, there are a few more variables I am dealing with. So I would like to learn how the two processes differ. Note that in the case of PERSON_06 the codes **do not always start in the first position**:

```
itemindex    circumstancecode    circumstanceid    circumstancetype    personid    reportnumber    
1            18                  4231703           Person              PERSON_01   REPORT1
2            17                  4231704           Person              PERSON_01   REPORT1
3            40.88               4231705           Person              PERSON_01   REPORT1
4            70.88               4231706           Person              PERSON_01   REPORT1
1            0                   4231707           Person              PERSON_02   REPORT1
1            61                  4231708           Person              PERSON_03   REPORT2
1            17                  4231709           Person              PERSON_04   REPORT3
1            40.88               4231710           Person              PERSON_05   REPORT4
1            0                   4231711           Person              PERSON_06   REPORT4
2            0                   4231712           Person              PERSON_06   REPORT4
3            55.88               4231713           Person              PERSON_06   REPORT4
```

I would like to structure this table like the following (code 1 thru 4 is based on `circumstancecode`) Note that for situations where there is no code to fill the code1-4 variables, I place an NA:

```
personid    reportnumber     circumstancetype    code_1    code1    code_3    code_4
PERSON_01   REPORT1          PERSON              18        17       40.88     70.88
PERSON_02   REPORT1          PERSON              0         NA       NA        NA
PERSON_03   REPORT2          PERSON              61        NA       NA        NA
PERSON_04   REPORT3          PERSON              17        NA       NA        NA
PERSON_05   REPORT4          PERSON              40.88     NA       NA        NA
PERSON_06   REPORT4          PERSON              0         0        55.88     NA
```

I would like to keep all the `code_` values as character because some values have letters in them, and I want to keep the exact formatting that is in the original data (so `40.88` is a char).

**For the final table,** there is a little bit different of a need. I would like to transform this table, which lists `personID's` who witnessed the car crash.

```
itemindex    personid    reportnumber
1            PERSON_55   REPORT_1
2            PERSON_56   REPORT_1
1            PERSON_44   REPORT_2
1            PERSON_32   REPORT_3
2            PERSON_34   REPORT_3
3            PERSON_35   REPORT_3
4            PERSON_36   REPORT_3
1            PERSON_21   REPORT_4
2            PERSON_22   REPORT_4
3            PERSON_23   REPORT_4
```

I would like each line to be a single crash `reportnumber` up to three variables as to list up to three witnesses:

```
reportnumber    witness1    witness2    witness3
REPORT_1        PERSON_55   PERSON_56   NA
REPORT_2        PERSON_44   NA          NA
REPORT_3        PERSON_32   PERSON_34   PERSON_35
REPORT_4        PERSON_21   PERSON_23   NA
```

***Thank you so much for your help!!!***

Comment: Please include some reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 examples are similar. I will provide some general explanation, and then the code for each example.

Using `tidyverse`, you can put your data into wide format with `pivot_wider`. In this case, you will first want to enumerate rows within each group, which can be done from `row_number()`. Then, with `pivot_wider`, you can specify the `id_cols` which is `vehicleid`. The column names are derived from the row numbers, and adding the prefix "impacttype_" in front of them. The values are taken from `impacttype`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(vehicleid) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = vehicleid, names_from = rn, values_from = impacttype, names_prefix = "impacttype_")
```

**Output**

```
  vehicleid impacttype_1 impacttype_2 impacttype_3
  <chr>            <int>        <int>        <int>
1 VEH1                 1           11           13
2 VEH012              10            8           NA
```

In the second example, you can use `slice_head` to get the first 4 rows in each group. Otherwise, the `pivot_wider` is relatively similar.

```
df2 %>%
  group_by(personid) %>%
  slice_head(n = 4) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(personid, reportnumber, circumstancetype), names_from = rn, values_from = circumstancecode, names_prefix = "code_")
```

**Output**

```
  personid  reportnumber circumstancetype code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
  <chr>     <chr>        <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 PERSON_01 REPORT1      Person             18       17   40.9   70.9
2 PERSON_02 REPORT1      Person              0       NA   NA     NA  
3 PERSON_03 REPORT2      Person             61       NA   NA     NA  
4 PERSON_04 REPORT3      Person             17       NA   NA     NA  
5 PERSON_05 REPORT4      Person             40.9     NA   NA     NA  
6 PERSON_06 REPORT4      Person              0        0   55.9   NA
```

In the third example, you already have an index to use for `pivot_wider`.

```
df3 %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = reportnumber, names_from = itemindex, values_from = personid, names_prefix = "witness")
```

**Output**

```
  reportnumber witness1  witness2  witness3  witness4 
  <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 REPORT_1     PERSON_55 PERSON_56 NA        NA       
2 REPORT_2     PERSON_44 NA        NA        NA       
3 REPORT_3     PERSON_32 PERSON_34 PERSON_35 PERSON_36
4 REPORT_4     PERSON_21 PERSON_22 PERSON_23 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

### Data 1

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat1 %>%
  select(-damageid) %>%
  pivot_wider(vehicleid, names_from = "itemindex", names_prefix = "impacttype_",
              values_from = "impacttype")
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   vehicleid impacttype_1 impacttype_2 impacttype_3
#   <chr>            <int>        <int>        <int>
# 1 VEH1                 1           11           13
# 2 VEH012              10            8           NA
```

As extra credit (in case you want to preserve `damageid`), you can widen both columns at once:

```r
dat1 %>%
  pivot_wider(vehicleid, names_from = "itemindex",
              values_from = c("impacttype", "damageid"))
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#   vehicleid impacttype_1 impacttype_2 impacttype_3 damageid_1 damageid_2 damageid_3
#   <chr>            <int>        <int>        <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
# 1 VEH1                 1           11           13       2433       2434       2435
# 2 VEH012              10            8           NA       2521       2522         NA
```

### Data 2

```r
dat2 %>%
  select(personid, reportnumber, circumstancetype,
         itemindex, circumstancecode) %>%
  pivot_wider(personid:circumstancetype,
              names_from = "itemindex", names_prefix = "code_",
              values_from = "circumstancecode")
# # A tibble: 6 x 7
#   personid  reportnumber circumstancetype code_1 code_2 code_3 code_4
#   <chr>     <chr>        <chr>             <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 PERSON_01 REPORT1      Person             18       17   40.9   70.9
# 2 PERSON_02 REPORT1      Person              0       NA   NA     NA  
# 3 PERSON_03 REPORT2      Person             61       NA   NA     NA  
# 4 PERSON_04 REPORT3      Person             17       NA   NA     NA  
# 5 PERSON_05 REPORT4      Person             40.9     NA   NA     NA  
# 6 PERSON_06 REPORT4      Person              0        0   55.9   NA
```

### Data 3

```r
dat3 %>%
  pivot_wider(reportnumber,
              names_from = "itemindex", names_prefix = "witness",
              values_from = "personid")
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   reportnumber witness1  witness2  witness3  witness4 
#   <chr>        <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
# 1 REPORT_1     PERSON_55 PERSON_56 <NA>      <NA>     
# 2 REPORT_2     PERSON_44 <NA>      <NA>      <NA>     
# 3 REPORT_3     PERSON_32 PERSON_34 PERSON_35 PERSON_36
# 4 REPORT_4     PERSON_21 PERSON_22 PERSON_23 <NA>
```

---

Raw data:

```r
dat1 <- structure(list(itemindex = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), damageid = c(2433L, 2434L, 2435L, 2521L, 2522L), impacttype = c(1L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 8L), vehicleid = c("VEH1", "VEH1", "VEH1", "VEH012", "VEH012")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
dat2 <- structure(list(itemindex = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), circumstancecode = c(18, 17, 40.88, 70.88, 0, 61, 17, 40.88, 0, 0, 55.88), circumstanceid = 4231703:4231713, circumstancetype = c("Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person", "Person"), personid = c("PERSON_01", "PERSON_01", "PERSON_01", "PERSON_01", "PERSON_02", "PERSON_03", "PERSON_04", "PERSON_05", "PERSON_06", "PERSON_06", "PERSON_06"), reportnumber = c("REPORT1", "REPORT1", "REPORT1", "REPORT1", "REPORT1", "REPORT2", "REPORT3", "REPORT4", "REPORT4", "REPORT4", "REPORT4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
dat3 <- structure(list(itemindex = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), personid = c("PERSON_55", "PERSON_56", "PERSON_44", "PERSON_32", "PERSON_34", "PERSON_35", "PERSON_36", "PERSON_21", "PERSON_22", "PERSON_23"), reportnumber = c("REPORT_1", "REPORT_1", "REPORT_2", "REPORT_3", "REPORT_3", "REPORT_3", "REPORT_3", "REPORT_4", "REPORT_4", "REPORT_4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```